# Get the equivalence of input("What is your name")

Tags: python, ocaml

In python, I can ask a question to a user in using

```
response = input("What is your name?") 
print(response)
```

How can I do such thing using Ocaml? I think I can 
use `read_line`, but I am not sure how to do it equivalently.

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/ocaml/example/9450/read-from-standard-input-and-print-to-standard-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
print_string "What is your name? ";
flush stdout;
let response = read_line () in
print_endline response
```

Comment: Can you tell me why I have to use flush stdout?

Comment: The standard output is buffered, and I believe there are systems where it won't appear unless you do the flush. Some systems will flush all pending output when you read from a terminal, and that seems to be happening for me on macOS. I would leave the flush for good measure, it might make a difference on some systems.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Not the first time I see that. I was just wandering why adding flush stdout?